# XSLT: Populate field alternatively in loop

Tags: xslt

I am beginner to XSLT and stuck with below conversion.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<Header>
<Data>
<field1>ABC</field1>
<field2>123</field2>
</Data>
<Data>
<field1>XYZ</field1>
<field2>456</field2>
</Data>
</Header>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<Header>
  <Data>
    <field1>ABC</field1>
    <field2>123</field2>
    <field1>XYZ</field1>
    <field2>456</field2>
  </Data>
</Header>
```

The main issue I am facing is populating field1 in alternative manner. I shall really appreciate any help here.

Thanks

Comment: Never, for any programming question, post screenshots of code.  Screenshots cannot be easily searched, copied, or pasted, and this frustrates future searches and present attempts to reproduce your problem or test provided solutions.  Post as text, formatted as code, instead.

Comment: I was having issues in adding the xml content, so posted it as screenshot. I changed it back to xml tags now. Thanks

Comment: Next, realize that you're expected to show what you've tried.  This lets those who can help focus on where you're stuck.  It also lets you avoid appearing to be demanding that code be written for you, which would not go over well here.

Answer (score 0):

There may be something missing from your explanation, because as presented the task is utterly trivial and requires no populating of any fields, alternatively or otherwise:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Header">
    <Header>
        <Data>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Data/*"/>
        </Data>
    </Header>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```